# Setting up virtual environments for python projects

Tags: python, pip, pyenv

I am trying to properly install python and set up virtual environments to make project development easier. Im stuck on how to install pip now. My question is this:

- Do I need to install pip in a specific way if I'm trying to set up virtual environments?

Here's what I've done so far...

1. installed pyenv
2. used pyenv to install python version 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9
3. set global pyenv to be python 3.9

Now I don't know hot to set up pip.

I did this:
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

and then:
python get-pip.py

..however when I go to verify pip was installed i get 'pip command not found'.

How do I properly set up pip so that I can create virtual environments and install packages for different environments?

Do I need to add pip to my PATH? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Pip comes with Python3.6+, you don't need to curl the installer

Comment: Ok so when I'm in a virtual environment, and specified which version of python I'll be running in that virtual environment, I'll be able to use pip automatically?

Comment: You should be able to. You might also want https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv

Comment: would help to add what operating system you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can create virtual environment directly from python with `venv`
(documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)
Example:

```
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

Activate the virtual environment

```
source /path/to/new/virtual/environment/bin/activate
```

Then you can install any package with

```
pip package-to-install
```